# MVC Web Api Authentication Fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-web-api2, .net-core

I got two MVC applications, MVC web and MVC web api. MVC application is running under "http://localhost:8241/" and MVC web api is running under "http://localhost:8243/". I set up cookie authentication in MVC application. here is the code in startup.cs

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
        {

            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
            options.AuthenticationScheme = "CookieAuthHRMS";
            options.CookieName = "access_token";

            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;

            options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Account/Login");
            options.LogoutPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Account/Logout");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");

        });
```

It is working fine. I can see access_token cookie by using chrome developer tool. So I want to add authentication under my web api project. So I did exactly the same code under Startup.cs of web api project. create controller named conjunctioncontroller to authenticate the web api. here is the code:

```
 [HttpPost("ConjunctionLI/{username}/{password}")]
    public async Task<bool> ConjunctionLI(string username, string password)
    {

        UsersEntity usrEty = await _usr.findsUsers(username, password);

        if (usrEty != null)
        {
            List<Claim> userClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("userId",usrEty.UserId.ToString()),
                new Claim("EmployeeId",usrEty.EmployeeID),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usrEty.UserName),
            };

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, "local"));

            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("CookieAuthHRMS", principal);
        }            

        return true;    
    }
```

In Mvc Web Application, I called conjunction controller after successful logging in. here is the code in Account controller's Login Action.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel lgvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(lgvm.UserName, lgvm.Password);
            string result;
            if(user!= null)
            {
                //call api service

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    string apiSec = @"http://localhost:8243/api/Conjunction/ConjunctionLI/" + lgvm.UserName + "//" + lgvm.Password;

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiSec, null);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }

                await SignInAsync(user, lgvm.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied","Account");
    }
```

I put [Authorize] tag in one of the web api controllers but still failed. Even though I used " await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("CookieAuthHRMS", principal);" like MVC web application, Authentication is still failed.

Is there any correct way to do it? How can I authenticate Web api project?

Best Rgds,
frog

Comment: An access token cannot work on two sites with different port numbers. What exactly is the error code you are getting?

Comment: no error, just dont work

Comment: Even though I am signing in, It is still not authorized.

Comment: Use same MachineKey in both the application's web.config file.

Comment: I dont have web.config file because of i am using .net core. how should i do this?

Comment: I think you still can [see link](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey.html). Although not used core yet myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worked by adding DataProtection middleware in Startup.cs.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(Configure);                      

        services.AddMvc();                                    

        services.AddDataProtection();

        services.ConfigureDataProtection(configure => {

            configure.SetApplicationName("HRMS");
            configure.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"));               
        });

    }
```